# Is there a way to plot 3 separate multiple regressions in the same plot?

Tags: r, regression, spss

| belonging | safety | wellbeing | negpol | pospol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.5 | 3.2 | 4.22 | 1.17 | 1.32 |
| 5.19 | 3.5 | 6.06 | 1.11 | 1.34 |
| 5.00 | 5.00 | 5.57 | 1.06 | 1.35 |

These are all scale vriables and some are subscales of larger measures.

negpol: 6 item measure on a scale of 1-4
pospol: 6 item measure on a scale of 1-4
safety: 10 item measure on a scale of 1-5
wellbeing: 16 item measure on a scale of 1-7
belonging: 16 item measure on a scale of 1-5

This my SPSS and R syntax for 3 regressions. I'm trying to plot them in ***one plot***. Is there a way?

```
fit1 <- lm(safety~negpol+pospol, data=data1)
fit2 <- lm(belonging~negpol+pospol, data=data1)
fit3 <- lm(wellbeing~negpol+pospol, data=data1)`
```

I'm not sure how I could do this!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily in base R with `abline`. Using the R-provided `mtcars` dataset:

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp , data = mtcars)
m2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)
m3 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + carb, data = mtcars)

plot(x = mtcars$disp, 
     y = mtcars$mpg)
abline(m1)
abline(m2, lty = 2, col = "purple")
abline(m3, lty = 3, col = "red")
```

[image]

---

The above compares apples to apples. In your question, you are comparing apples to oranges. If you want to look at the effect of `negpol` while controlling for `pospol` on three different variables with different scales (however that are somewhat similar (1 to 5 and 1 to 7), you could try something like:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 25
data1 <- data.frame(belonging = runif(n, 1, 5),
                    safety = runif(n, 1, 5),
                    wellbeing = runif(n, 1,7),
                    negpol =  runif(n, 1, 4),
                    pospol = runif(n, 1, 4))

fit1 <- lm(safety ~ negpol + pospol, data = data1)
fit2 <- lm(belonging ~ negpol + pospol, data = data1)
fit3 <- lm(wellbeing ~ negpol + pospol, data = data1)

plot(NA, xlim = c(1, 4),
     ylim = c(1, 7),
     axes = FALSE,
     xlab = "Negpol", 
     ylab = "Value")
axis(1, at = 1:4)
axis(2, las = 2)
axis(4, at = 1:5, las = 2)
points(x = data1$negpol,
       y = data1$safety, pch = 21, bg = "maroon")
points(x = data1$negpol,
       y = data1$belonging, pch = 21, bg = "slateblue")
points(x = data1$negpol,
       y = data1$wellbeing, pch = 21, bg = "yellow2")
abline(fit1, col = "maroon", lwd = 2)
abline(fit2, col = "slateblue", lwd = 2)
abline(fit3, col = "yellow2", lwd = 2)
```

Which would give you something like:

[image]

though that may not be the best approach and you may want to reconsider exactly what comparisons you are seeking.

Comment: thank you!, 

I'm not sure I understand > plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$mpg) <
how does it account for the other IVs? and will this work for me considering my 3 regressions have different DVs?

Comment: @SrishtiKaturi what are you regressing? Typically regression looks to predict Outcome (O; or DV) given Exposure (E) , while accounting for other Confounding factors (C). So O ~ E +C. Here, I modeled the `disp` effect on `mpg` (mpg ~ disp) I three ways: (1) crude, (2) controlling for `hp`, and controlling for `hp` and `carb`. I plotted the main outcome (mpg) vs exposure (disp). If you are modeling three different outcomes, it may be best if you edit your question to include sample data. I have no idea if safety, belonging, and and wellbeing are linear, dichotomous, share the same scale, etc.

Comment: added some sample data!

Comment: @SrishtiKaturi Thank you for adding some sample data! There may be some confusion about what a model does. What would you like the x-axis to be?

Comment: I edited the question to expand your sample data so that a meaningful regression could be ran on it, but my sense is this may not be the best approach overall for your data

Comment: @jpmsith Thank you! I understand what you're saying about comparing apples to oranges. I decided those three regressions were the best for me. The only reason I'm trying to fit them on one plot is for a posyer for a conference. People don't want to look at 3 plots...